# offsetWidth returns 0, but console in dev tool gives the correct value

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to understand why my tabActive.offsetWidth is 0 while I type exactly that code into console of dev tool and it returns 135. Anyone's been to the same problem? :( [here is the image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxsPK.png)

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the js so you can see why it happens. The element is probably hidden or the content have not rendered

Comment: Put the 6 lines of code on Th he question

Comment: Please don't use images/screenshots for any text-based content like code, error messages, data etc. See also: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)